# How to move text under image in UITextView?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, uibezierpath, textkit

I want to write text in textView and later when I add an image to textView I just want this text move under that image. So.. when i made image smaller than bounds of textView text stays on the same line and only moves to the right and appears near by the image, but when i made an image the same size in width as textView its just stays at the same (start) position  and doesn't moves at all.. here is code I use:

```
UIBezierPath *exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(_imageView.frame),
                                                                                        CGRectGetMinY(_imageView.frame), CGRectGetWidth(_imageView.frame),
                                                                                     CGRectGetHeight(_imageView.frame))];

self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths= @[exclusionPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, You can put `UITextView` with clear background color, on top of `UIImageView` and *animate* `UIImageView` as per your requirement. When the size of `UIImageView` changes you can also change `UITextView` *frame*.

Answer (score 0):

Set UITextViewDelegate in Your Code

```
-(void) textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [TextReview scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([TextReview.text length], 0)];
}
```

When You enter text in your textview then it automatically scroll of text in scrollview.

[image]